# WindowsForms difference to simple Console App

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, console, interaction

I currently started to "port" my console projects to WinForms, but it seems I am badly failing doing that.

I am simply used to a console structure:

I got my classes interacting with each other depending on the input coming from the console.
A simple flow:

```
Input -> ProcessInput -> Execute -> Output -> wait for input
```

Now I got this big Form1.cs (etc.) and the "Application.Run(Form1);"
But I really got no clue how my classes can interact with the form and create a flow like I described above.

I mean, I just have these "...._Click(object sender....)" for each "item" inside the form.
Now I do not know where to place / start my flow / loop, and how my classes can interact with the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, actually (though I can sympathize with your confusion)...

**1. Input**
Have a `TextBox` and a `Button`. When the user clicks on the button, treat whatever's in your `TextBox` as your input.

**2. Process Input**
In a console app, the user is unable to do anything while you're processing input. The analogue to this in a Windows Forms app is to disable the mechanism by which the user can supply input. So, set your `TextBox.Enabled = false` and `Button.Enabled = false`.

**3. Execute**
Run whatever method you want to execute.

**4. Output**
Have some kind of message displayed on the form. This could be simply another `TextBox`, or a `RichTextBox`... whatever you want.

**5. Wait for Input**
Once your method from step 3 has executed, you've displayed the output in part 4, you can go ahead and re-activate your mechanism for accepting input: `TextBox.Enabled = true` and `Button.Enabled = true`.

So basically your code should like something like this:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        myInputTextBox.Enabled = false;
        myButton.Enabled = false;

        var input = ParseInput(myInputTextBox.Text);

        var output = ExecuteMethodWithInput(input);

        myOutputTextBox.Text = FormatOutput(output);

    } finally {
        myInputTextBox.Enabled = true;
        myButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can have your form provide a set of controls for inputting data (ie: one or more TextBox controls).  If you have a button that the user clicks, and you want to process, just double click on teh button.  This will give you an event handler like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Process Input from TextBox controls, etc.
     // Execute method
     // Set output (To other controls, most likely)
}
```

That's it - the "loop" goes away, since the standard Windows message pump takes its place.

Comment: so I have to look at each event handler like it is a "little flow"?

Comment: @daemonfire300: Basically, it's an "entry point" to your processing.  You're saying "when the user clicks this button, I want to run this code..." so it provides a way for you to "process" and start your flow control.